# A selected value of a <select> can modify another <select>?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have 2 selects and what i wanna do is (without refreshing the page): the moment the user selects a value from the first select (value1 or value2) changes the second select: if he choosed value1, then he have a select with values a, b, c, d; if he choosed value2, then he can choose on second select e, f, g, h.
Is this possible without refreshing the page?

Edit: I know you all are not here to write code for others; just wanted to keep it simple instead of posting all my messy code :). So, what i want to do, is to modify the second select id=selectAccessiblePaths with the onchange function applyGroupSelection()

```
function initDivWithConfig () {
  divWithInfo = document.createElement('div');
  divWithInfo.class = 'divWithInfoControls';
  divWithInfo.style.position = 'absolute';
  divWithInfo.style.top = '10px';
  divWithInfo.style.width = '100%';
  divWithInfo.style.textAlign = 'center';
  var groupToDisplay = '<p id="pSelectGroup" style="display: block;">Select the user group: ';
  groupToDisplay += '<select id="selectGroup" onchange="applyGroupSelection()">';
  groupToDisplay += '<option selected>Nothing selected</option>';
  for ( var g in userGroups ) {
    groupToDisplay += '<option>' + g + '</option>';
  }   
  groupToDisplay += '</select></p>';
  divWithInfo.innerHTML += groupToDisplay;
  groupSelected = 'group1';
  var accessiblePathsToDisplay = '<p id="pSelectAccessiblePaths" style="display: none;">Select the accessible paths: ';
  accessiblePathsToDisplay += '<select id="selectAccessiblePaths" onchange="applyAccessiblePathsSelection()">';
  accessiblePathsToDisplay += '<option selected>Nothing selected</option>';
  for ( var ap=0; ap<userGroups[ groupSelected ].accessiblePaths.length; ap++ ) {
    var pathsForThisGroup = userGroups[ groupSelected ].accessiblePaths[ ap ][ "ns0:svg" ][ "groupPathsName" ];
    accessiblePathsToDisplay += '<option>' + pathsForThisGroup + '</option>';
  }  
  accessiblePathsToDisplay += '</select></p>';
  divWithInfo.innerHTML += accessiblePathsToDisplay;
  document.body.appendChild( divWithInfo );
}

function applyGroupSelection () {
  groupSelected = "group2";
  hideUnhideObject( "pSelectGroup" );
  hideUnhideObject( "pSelectAccessiblePaths" );
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible and very common. Use a `change` handler on the first `<select>` that gets its value, and modifies the second `<select>`

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+chained+selects

Comment: If you're having trouble getting it to work, please show the code you tried. We're not going to write it for you, but we'll help you fix your errors so you can learn from your mistakes.

Comment: [Bonus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy with HTML, CSS and a JavaScript line:

**HTML**:

```
<select id='firstselect' onchange="document.getElementById('secondselect').className=this.value">
    <option value='select'>Select a value</option>
    <option value='value1'>Value1</option>
    <option value='value2'>Value2</option>
</select>

<select id='secondselect'>
    <option value='a'>a</option>
    <option value='b'>b</option>
    <option value='c'>c</option>
    <option value='d'>d</option>
    <option value='e'>e</option>
    <option value='f'>f</option>
    <option value='g'>g</option>
    <option value='h'>h</option>
</select>
```

**CSS**:

```
#secondselect, #secondselect option {
    display: none;
}

#secondselect.value1, #secondselect.value2 {
    display: block;
}

.value1 option[value="a"], .value1 option[value="b"], .value1 option[value="c"], .value1 option[value="d"] {
    display: block !important;    
}

.value2 option[value="e"], .value2 option[value="f"], .value2 option[value="g"], .value2 option[value="h"] {
    display: block !important;    
}
```

See in action: http://jsfiddle.net/nukz3ns3/

**UPDATED**:
Also you can do a function for change to default value when `firstselect` change:

```
function setSecondSelect( select ){
    var secondselect = document.getElementById('secondselect');
    secondselect.className=select.value;
    secondselect.selectedIndex = (select.value === 'value1')?0:4;
}
```

See how it works: http://jsfiddle.net/nukz3ns3/1/

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible by using ajax post method.

Comment: What does AJAX have to do with this?

Comment: On selection of value from first select box you can load your second select box according.

Comment: That's one way. But you can also have the values in an array or object.

Comment: Ok then  Onchange event of first select box by using javacript you can add values in second select box.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible if you used ajax.
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Why does it have to use AJAX? That's only if the values of the second select come from the server.

Comment: Yes, you can used purely javascript if your second value is hard coded

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#select1").change(function() { 
          if($(this).data('options') == undefined){
           $(this).data('options',$('#select2 option').clone());} 

        var id = $(this).val();
       // alert(id);
        var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[value=' + id + ']');

        if(options.val() == undefined){
            //$('#select2').hide();
            $('#select2').prop("disabled",true);
        }else{
            //$('#select2').show();
            $('#select2').prop("disabled",false);
         $('#select2').html(options);
        }
      });
   });

</script>



<div class="pageCol1">
        <div class="panel">
        <div class="templateTitle">Request for Items</div>  
        <table class="grid" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr class="gridAlternateRow">
                <td><b>Item to be Request</b></td>
                <td>
                <select name="select1" id="select1">
                        <option value="1">--Select--</option>
                        <option value="2">Stationaries</option>
                        <option value="3">Computer Accessories</option>
                        <option value="4">Bottle</option>
                        <option value="5">Chair</option>
                        <option value="6">Office File</option>
                        <option value="7">Phone Facility</option>
                        <option value="8">Other Facilities</option> 
                </select>
              </td></tr>
              <tr><td>
              <b>Category</b>
              </td> 
              <td>  
                <select name="select2" id="select2" >
                  <option value="1">--Select--</option>
                    <option value="2">Note Books</option>
                    <option value="2">Books</option>
                    <option value="2">Pen</option>
                    <option value="2">Pencil</option>
                    <option value="2">Eraser</option>
                    <option value="2">Drawing sheets</option>
                    <option value="2">Others</option>
                    <option value="3">Laptop</option>
                    <option value="3">PC</option>
                    <option value="3">CPU</option>
                    <option value="3">Monitor</option>
                    <option value="3">Mouse</option>
                    <option value="3">Keyboard</option>
                    <option value="3">Mouse Pad</option>
                    <option value="3">Hard Disk</option>
                    <option value="3">Pendrive</option>
                    <option value="3">CD/DVD Writer</option>
                    <option value="3">RAM</option>
                    <option value="3">Mother Board</option>
                    <option value="3">SMPS</option>
                    <option value="3">Network Cables</option>
                    <option value="3">Connectors</option>
                    <option value="7">Land Line</option>
                    <option value="7">BlackBerry </option>
                    <option value="7">Other</option>
                  </select> 
                </td>
            </tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

your html can be of your required format.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to populate the second select from existing options,
Try using [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) on a `change` handler

```
  $("firstselect").change(function() {
        var options = $("secondselect").filter(function() { 
    //return the options you want to display
        });
        $("secondselect").html(options);
   });
```

Or if you want to retrieve options from server, use AJAX and form the options
and do an `innerHTML` as above.